# How to check whether element loaded successfully in a HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

Is there a way to check whether the element in a HTML page has loaded successfully ?
Like using Javascript **document.readyState** returns 'complete' if the document (or HTML page) isloaded successfully as a whole.
In case of any element loading asynchronously (like AJAX), Is there a way to check whether the particular element has loaded successfully using Javascript without having access to the HTML source. Consider I just know the id of the element.
Is there a way to do **document.getElementById(ID).??? or any other way** is my question.

Comment: if you have access to the content loaded via 
AJAX then add an onload to the element you want to check when it loads

Comment: @Billy : Thanks for answering and that solved my question! Please give it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way may be:

```
$('#yourElementSelector')
.load(function(){
    //your code here
})
.error(function(){
//your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to the content loaded via AJAX then add an onload to the element you want to check when it loads